# Nothing is drawn after pygame instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to create a 2d video game with pygame.

After executing the following code:

```
from ship import Ship
from settings import Settings
import sys
import pygame


class Alien_invasion:
    """class to manage the game"""

    def __init__(self):
        """initialise the game and create game ressources"""
        pygame.init()
        #print("ouzou")
        self.settings=Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.settings.screen_height,self.settings.screen_width)
        
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien invasion")
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        
    def run_game(self):
        """start the game by calling a main loop"""
        while True:
            print("izann")
             # wait keyboard or mouse event
            for event in pygame.event:
                if event.type == pygame.quit():
                    sys.exit()
                # draw the screen after all the changes occured
                self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
                self.ship.blitme()
                print("izan")
                pygame.display.flip()
                print("izan ssin")

if __name__ == "main":
    partie = Alien_invasion()
    partie.run_game()
```

I'm expecting to have a pygame window but instead the console prints:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.0)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

and nothing happens after!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) is a function and uninitialize all PyGame modules. When you do

> ```py
> if event.type == pygame.quit():
> ```

the function is called and all PyGame modules are uninitialized.

The *type* attribute of [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object indicates the type of event. You need to compare the event type to the enumeration constant that identifies the event. The *quit* event is identified by `pygame.QUIT` (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module):

Hence, you have to compete with `pygame.QUIT` instead of `pygame.quit()`:

```py
for event in pygame.event:
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

Additionally there is an [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) issue. You have to draw the scene and update the display in the application loop rather than then event loop:

```py
from ship import Ship
from settings import Settings
import sys
import pygame


class Alien_invasion:
    """class to manage the game"""

    def __init__(self):
        """initialise the game and create game ressources"""
        pygame.init()
        #print("ouzou")
        self.settings=Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.settings.screen_height,self.settings.screen_width)
        
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien invasion")
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        
    def run_game(self):
        """start the game by calling a main loop"""
        while True:
            print("izann")
             # wait keyboard or mouse event
            for event in pygame.event:
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            
            # INDENTATION

            #<--|
    
            # draw the screen after all the changes occured
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()
            print("izan")
            pygame.display.flip()
            print("izan ssin")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    partie = Alien_invasion()
    partie.run_game()
```

Comment: thanks every thing you say is useful for me, finally it works, just in the last line it's "if __name__ == "__main__": "

Answer (score 0):

the lines with '###' are my corrections.

```
from ship import Ship
from settings import Settings
import sys
import pygame


class Alien_invasion:
    """class to manage the game"""

    def __init__(self):
        """initialise the game and create game ressources"""
        pygame.init()
        #print("ouzou")
        self.settings=Settings()
        self.screen = 
           pygame.display.set_mode(self.settings.screen_height,self.settings.screen_width)
        
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien invasion")
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        
    def run_game(self):
        """start the game by calling a main loop"""
        while True:
            print("izann")
             # wait keyboard or mouse event
            for event in pygame.event.get():      ###syntax
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:     ###syntax
                    sys.exit()
           # draw the screen after all the changes occurred   ###the following should not in the pygame event get loop
           self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
           self.ship.blitme()
           print("izan")
           pygame.display.flip()
           print("izan ssin")

if __name__ == "__main__":       ###syntax wrong
    partie = Alien_invasion()
    partie.run_game()
```